# how to start with ASP.NET MVC 3 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I going to start a new project in my company in which are involved the use of MVC 3, now this is the first time that we are using this framework, and i have a couple of questions,

1. It's recommended to start with MVC3 and not from the MVC2?
2. Any Tutorials in specific that you can recommend?
3. This framework have full integration with jQuery?

Comment: For tutorials, take a look at the free ones at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs including the Music Store. Also, if you want to pay for some screencasts, see tekpub.com MVC Concepts and Real World MVC3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, use MVC 3 first. Having Razor is such a boon to productivity, I find.
2. The Plural Sight video tutorials on the ASP.NET website are very good
3. Yes, the framework has brilliant integration with jQuery as standard

Answer (score 2):

[Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430234043) by Adam Freeman and Steven sanders is a one stop learning for MVC framework with hands on project development. Hope this one fulfils your appetite for learning MVC

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommended using Razor, however keep in mind that there are other view engines available too.

Definitive go to MS ASP.NET MVC site, Pluralsight and the MVC team blogs

Yes, it's totally integrated with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

No question about doing Razor -- it really makes development much, much better.

I think the real question at this point is "Should I start on MVC4 or just use MVC3?" Their dev cycle is pretty tight, in many cases you are better off aiming at the version of the framework under development lest you end up needing to upgrade immediately after publishing.